# Audiokit Bluetooth MIDI button broken?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, midi, audiokit

The Bluetooth MIDI connect button had been working on AudioKit 5.0 Beta, but when I installed 5.3.2 the button does not have any action or message. I was also using Xcode13 beta and now use Xcode13 release version. I tried a very simple program with just a button that goes to this line:
@IBOutlet weak var bluetoothButton: BluetoothMIDIButton!
and it still does not work when run. Other programs that use BLE MIDI on the same IPAD work fine, and all permissions (Bluetooth always, peripheral usage) seem to be set correctly. If I connect first with another app, then all the other MIDIsend/receive functions work properly in my app. Is there some new requirement that I am missing?